# Convert Model to ViewModel without automapper

Tags: c#

Hi this is my convert a Ilist of model to a Ilist of ViewModel method

```
public static IList<PostViewModel> ConvertToPostViewModelList(this IList<Post> posts)
        {
            return posts.Select(ConvertToPostViewModel).ToList();
        }
```

and also this is the ConvertToPostViewModel

```
 public static PostViewModel ConvertToPostViewModel(this Post post)
        {
            var blogPostViewModel = new PostViewModel
                {
                    Id = post.Id,
                    Body = post.Body,
                    Summary = post.Summary,
                    Title = post.Title,
                    Category = post.Category,
                    CreationDate = post.CreationDate,
                    SelectedCategory = post.CategoryId,
                    SelectedTag = post.TagId,
                    Tag = post.Tag,
                    UrlSlug = post.UrlSlug

                };

            return blogPostViewModel;
        }
```

what is the problem with this , I got this error View :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blog.Domain.Model.Post]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Blog.Web.UI.ViewModels.PostViewModel]'.
```

then ??  I convert the Ilist of Model to ViewModel via this :

```
return posts.Select(ConvertToPostViewModel).ToList();
```

then what is going on ??

what I have done in action

```
 public ActionResult  Posts()
        {
            var blogPost = _blogRepository.GetAllPost();
            var blogPostViewModel = blogPost.ConvertToPostViewModelList();
            return View("Posts", blogPostViewModel);
        }
```

and in View

```
@model IList<Blog.Web.UI.ViewModels.PostViewModel>
```

Comment: Post the code where the error is thrown.

Comment: It looks like you are passing the `Post` to your view, instead of the resulting `PostViewModel`. Did you update your call to `View()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Two possibilities:**

1. The method you posted is not the one being matched.  You can verify this easily by throwing an exception in your controller action and seeing if it gets thrown.  This could be the result of either: (a) an overloaded `Posts` controller action, where the other is being matched; or, (b) a custom route that is intercepting the request.
2. You originally returned the domain object in testing, but after changing the controller action to set the model to the `PostViewModel`, you forgot to recompile your MVC project.  Try recompiling your solution and see if the results change.